# Function simpleNameGame is undefined

Tags: javascript

```
//main\
<html>
<head>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="functions.js">                                                  </script>
</head>
<body>

<head>CODE CHALLENGE</head>

<p>Andrea</p><p></p>
<script>

document.write(simpleNameGame("Andrea"));

</script>
</body>
 </html>
   // functions \
    function simpleNameGame(name)
  {
 var x = name.slice(1,name.length);
  var song = name + ", " + name + ", bo-b" + x + "</br>" + "Banana-fana fo-f"                              + x + "</br> Fee-fy-mo-m" + x + "</br>" + name + "! </br>";
return song;
   }
```

The console says that the function simpleNameGame(name) is undefined . and that there is an unexpected string , so how do I fix that?

Comment: Please use specific titles that summarize the issue instead of "Please help me".

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep your script code in script tags.

Example Snippet:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="functions.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <head>CODE CHALLENGE</head>

  <p>Andrea</p>
  <p></p>
  <script>
    document.write(simpleNameGame("Andrea"));

    function simpleNameGame(name) {
      var x = name.slice(1, name.length);
      var song = name + ", " + name + ", bo-b" + x + "</br>" + "Banana-fana fo-f" + x + "</br> Fee-fy-mo-m" + x + "</br>" + name + "! </br>";
      return song;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JavaSCript function inside the script block `<script></script>`

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
   function simpleNameGame(name)
  {
 var x = name.slice(1,name.length);
  var song = name + ", " + name + ", bo-b" + x + "</br>" + "Banana-fana fo-f"                              + x + "</br> Fee-fy-mo-m" + x + "</br>" + name + "! </br>";
return song;
   }</script>
</head>
<body>

<head>CODE CHALLENGE</head>

<p>Andrea</p><p></p>
<script>

document.write(simpleNameGame("Andrea"));

</script>
</body>
 </html>
```